# Child grid custom command button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a question based on my current situation, I have a grid with ClientDetail / Child grid inside of it. In my parent grid there is a custom command button, let say...

```
"columns.Command(
   command => { command.Custom("Edit").Click("showEdit"); command.Destroy();   
 }).Width(160);"
```

and also i had my custom command button as well in my child grid, let say...

```
"columns.Command(
 command => { command.Custom("Edit").Click("showSubEdit"); command.Destroy();    
 }).Width(160);"
```

Those 2 custom command should call different function which is "**showEdit**" & "**showSubEdit**". The problem is, every time custom command in child grid triggered, it always calls its parent's function which is "showEdit", however the child grid should call "showSubEdit".

Is there something i missed ?

NB :

```
function showEdit(e) {
...
}
function showSubEdit(e) {
...
}
```

Grid Code :

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ActivityModel>()
        .Name("GridActivity")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            //columns.Template(t => { }).Title("No").ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(data) #").Width(50);
            columns.Bound(c => c._id).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ActivityType.TypeTitle).Title("Type").Width(80);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ActivityTitle).Title("Title").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(c => c.DependenciesStr).Title("Dependencies").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ResourcesStr).Title("Resources").Width(120);
            columns.Bound(c => c.FromStr).Title("From");
            columns.Bound(c => c.ToStr).Title("To");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Status).Title("Status").Width(90).Format("{0:0.00} %").Width(85);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Weight).Title("Weight").Format("{0:0.00} %").Width(85);
            columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Edit").Click("showEdit"); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 290px;" })
        .Groupable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20 }).Refresh(true))
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Model(c => c.Id(p => p._id))
            .Read(read => read.Action("ProjectActivities_Read", "Project", new { projectId = ViewBag.ProjectId }))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ProjectActivities_Destroy", "Project", new { projectId = ViewBag.ProjectId }))
        )
        .Events(x => x.DataBound("resetRowNumber"))
    )
</div>

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("TabStrip_#=_id#")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add().Text("Sub Activity").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ActivityModel>()
                        .Name("GridChild_#=_id#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(x => x._id).Visible(false);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.ActivityType.TypeTitle).Title("Type");
                            columns.Bound(x => x.ActivityTitle).Title("Title").Width(150);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.DependenciesStr).Title("Dependencies").Width(150);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.ResourcesStr).Title("Resources").Width(150);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.FromStr).Title("From");
                            columns.Bound(x => x.ToStr).Title("To");
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Status).Title("Status").Width(90).Format("{0:0.00} %").Width(85);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Weight).Title("Weight").Format("{0:0.00} %").Width(85);
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Edit").Click("showEditSub"); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
                        })
                        .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10 }).Refresh(true))
                        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .Model(x => x.Id(y => y._id))
                            .Read(read => read.Action("ProjectSubActivities_Read", "Project", new { projectId = ViewBag.ProjectId, activityId = "#=_id#" }))
                            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ProjectSubActivities_Destroy", "Project", new { projectId = ViewBag.ProjectId, activityId = "#=_id#" }))
                        )
                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .ToClientTemplate())
                </text>
                );
            }).ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please share the Grid creation code, as when you create a child grid you have to link them to the parent via name like: **.Name("grdChild_#=ParentUID#")**

Answer (score 0):

I got around the bubbling by checking if the element shown by the first command event is visible:

```
function showDetailsLevel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    originatingId = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")).Id

    var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");  

    if (!$("#Details").is(":visible")) {                  
        wnd.center();
        wnd.open();
        var grid = $("#DetailGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.read();
    }   
}
```